# UWP Build on Jenkins

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, continuous-integration, uwp

I'm trying to build a C# UWP on Jenkins, however I'm getting the following error:

```
XamlCompiler error WMC1006: Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Runtime.dll'
```

Build tools 2015 and VS2015 are both installed on the Jenkins server, and the build script is targeting version 14 of MSbuild

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A clean source code tree straight out of version control for a UWP app needs NuGet to run to find dependencies specified in the project.json files.

As a dev, this is something Visual Studio 2015 normally does for you.

On a build server, you will need to run the command-line NuGet 3.x executable so that all the dependencies are pulled down on your build machine before your build runs (MSBuild part).

Go to http://dist.nuget.org/index.html to get hold of the command-line NuGet.exe.

The command will have the form of `nuget.exe restore [MyApp.sln]`.

Comment: This solved the issue, adding nuget.exe to the CI server and its PATH environment variable, as well as adding in a build step to restore the packages got it to build.